# CQRS is failing in filtering scenario in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cqrs

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project I am using CQRS pattern.

I have list all projects with query parameters. For limit and offset it is working but for other properties it throws server error.

My list method looks like:

```
    public class List
    {
        public class ProjectList
        {
            public List<ProjectForListDto> Projects { get; set; }
        }

        public class Query : IRequest<ProjectList>
        {
            public Query(int? limit, int? offset, string organizationName, int? organizationId, string status)
            {
                Limit = limit;
                Offset = offset;
                OrganizationName = organizationName;
                OrganizationId = organizationId;
                Status = status;
            }

            public int? Limit { get; set; }
            public int? Offset { get; set; }
            public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
            public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }

        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Query, ProjectList>
        {
            private readonly DataContext _context;
            private readonly IMapper _mapper;

            public Handler(DataContext context, IMapper mapper)
            {
                _context = context;
                _mapper = mapper;
            }

            public async Task<ProjectList> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var queryable = _context.Projects
                                        .AsQueryable();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.OrganizationName) || 
                                          request.OrganizationId > 0 ||
                                          !string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Status))
                {
                    queryable = queryable.Where(x =>
                        x.Organization.Name == request.OrganizationName ||
                        x.OrganizationId == request.OrganizationId || x.Status.ToString("G") 
               == request.Status);
                }

                var projects = await queryable.Skip(request.Offset ?? 0)
                                              .Take(request.Limit ?? 50)
                                              .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

                return new ProjectList
                {
                    Projects = _mapper.Map<List<Project>, List<ProjectForListDto>>(projects)
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

My controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List.ProjectList>> List(int? offset, int? limit, 
        string organizationName, int? organizationId, string status) => await 
        Mediator.Send(new List.Query(limit, offset, organizationName, organizationId, status));
```

By default without any params it returns all projects which is ok, also I can set offset and limit as well, but for scenario organizationId, status and organizationName it fails.
Exception I am getting:

```
fail: API.Middleware.ErrorHandlingMiddleware[0]
      SERVER ERROR
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Project>
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<Organization>, 
        inner: p => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(p, "OrganizationId"), 
        outerKeySelector: o => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(o, "Id"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Project, Organization>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(p => p.Inner.Name == __request_OrganizationName_0 || (Nullable<int>)p.Outer.OrganizationId == __request_OrganizationId_1 || p.Outer.Status.ToString("G") == __request_Status_2)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

Comment: My guess is that the `ToString("G")` cannot be converted to a SQL query. If this is so, you have to redesign this part.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I also tried without ToString("G"), but I am failing in organizationName scenario as well which is pure string

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @WiktorZychla uodated question please check out exception

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks a lot I used before int for status changed to enum and it worked

Answer (score 0):

EF Core doesn't know how to do GROUP JOIN's properly at this time. I had to manually perform a group join on the returned resultset in my code after performing the query.

In a weather forecast sample I wrote, I had to do the following to perform a group join:

```
var locationForecasts = await locations.Join(inner: forecasts,
    outerKeySelector: location => location.Id,
    innerKeySelector: forecast => forecast.LocationId,
    resultSelector: (location, forecast) =>
        new
        {
            location,
            forecast
        }).ToListAsync();

var result = locationForecasts.GroupBy(x => x.location.Id)
    .Select(x => new WeatherForecast
    {
        LocationId = x.Key,
        LocationName = x.FirstOrDefault().location.LocationName,
        Forecasts = x.Select(y => y.forecast)
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

The point here is to perform a JOIN in SQL, then return the result and then perform the GroupBy in the application layer.

Hopefully EF will support this soon, but in the meantime, this is the workaround I've been using. The materialized SQL query seems to spit out the same code for Join and GroupJoin anyway, so I don't believe it's a performance concern.